# Is there a program capable of producing a nifty visual representation of file and directory ages?

Tags: software-recommendation

Ubuntu's [Disc Usage Analyser](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/baobab/) can produce a very nifty set of rings charts in which area is proportional to drive space used by directories. Is there a program capable of producing a similar (or better) visual representation of other directory and file characteristics? The specific characteristic I want to look at is file ages (last modification times) or, if possible, extrapolated directory ages.

Comment: If there isn't such a thing, it should be invented.  Of course one could use graphviz or other packages to visualize arbitrary kinds of information....

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is not such nifty software yet. Instead, you can install smartctl which gives useful info about the disk wearing, though in plain old text.